# Using PS find size of file which is being copied

Tags: powershell, filesystems, filesize

Let's suppose I'm copying a file from `\\serverA\folder\file.iso` to `\\serverB\folder\file.iso`.

I'd like with the help of PS to find out the current file size in the destination folder.

I tried "Get-Item"(examplese below) and "Get-ChildItem", but both of them show non-relevant information

```
Get-Item -Path ("\\serverB\folder\file.iso").Length
```

However, every time I go to file explorer and click RMC -> Properties, it calculates\estimates the actual file size. And after this, if I run the PS script, it'll calculate the size that I just saw in Properties.

I suppose it's something about the filesystem, but I haven't found any resources that describe how to do that in PS.

Comment: `(Get-Item -Path ("\\serverB\folder\file.iso").Length)/1MB`

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh thanks, but it gives the same output, but converted to MB

Comment: I am not following here. Can you provide the sample for actual vs expected output.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh it's hard to provide a sample, but I'll try. When the file is being copied, and I'm using command that you've specified, I'm receiving 0.923MB, but actual size of file is 487.14MB(I can verify it clicking RMC on the file and choose "Properties"). So, I'd like to see the same result when I'm using PS

Comment: That should be `(Get-Item -Path "\\serverB\folder\file.iso").Length /1MB`. BTW, did you wait until the file was fully copied?

Comment: @Theo I want to know the size of copied part at this moment, so waiting till the end of copying doesn't work for me. That's why I created this post :/